# Moving std::function with member function

Tags: c++, c++11, std, move, std-function

I've written a super simple event system using `std::function`.

It amounts to

```
std::vector<Delegate<Args ...>*> _delegates;
```

Where `Delegate` is an alias of `std::function`

```
template <typename ... Args>
using Delegate = std::function<void(Args ...)>;
```

With the event's `operator()`, `operator+=`, and `operator-=` overloaded.

```
operator() calls all of the listening functions.
operator+= adds a listener.
operator-= removes a listener.
```

Hooking them up looks like this...

```
Foo::Foo(Bar& bar)
{
    ...

    m_bar_ptr = &bar;

    using namespace std::placeholders;

    event_receiver =
    Delegate<const Bar&, const SomeBarData>
    (std::bind(&Foo::OnEventReceived, this, _1, _2));
    bar.BarEvent += event_receiver;

    ...
}
```

Everything works as intended, but when I move the owner of a `Delegate` I end up having to unhook and duplicate the code for the initial hook up (as expected).

It looks like this...

```
Foo& Foo::operator=(Foo&& other)
{
    ...

    m_bar_ptr = other.m_bar_ptr;
    other.m_bar_ptr = nullptr;

    m_bar_ptr->BarEvent -= other.event_receiver;

    using namespace std::place_holders;

    event_receiver =
    Delegate<const Bar&, const SomeBarData>
    (std::bind(&Foo::OnEventReceived, this, _1, _2));
    bar.BarEvent += event_receiver;

    ...
}
```

Aside from having to keep a handle to Bar, which is acceptable, this is a lot of code to re-target the `Delegate`...and leaves a lot of room for error.

I like the simplicity of these events (though I am open to suggestions), but what I'm really looking for is a way to keep this event system and simplify moves.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using a vector of raw pointers to `std::function` ?

Comment: Because `std::functions` can't be compared for equality.  I'm storing them in an `std::vector` and need to be able to find them for removal and to avoid adding duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me like you aren't using the move assignment properly, you aren't moving anything but creating copies.
The event_receiver is created from scratch and not moved.

I know its tempting to write a move function thinking it will automatically be more efficient.
But when writing such function the efficiency is gained from moving the object members efficiently.

In your case I think you can simply use a copy assignment and let the dtor do the unregistration, or change the move function to move the object members.

Comment: In this case, during the move Foo is only creating a new `Delegate` (which is very light-weight, just an `std::function`), but Foo itself could be a large object that benefits from the move.